# creating a database outside the application context

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an app factory like so

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(environment):
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(config[environment])

  db.init_app(app)
  # ... etc

  return app
```

then, I have a script which fetches CSVs outside of the context of the application. This script is a cron which is run every x hours

I want to update the sqlite database somehow that the application is using. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy only needs an app context to operate. You can create an app context manually.

```
app = create_app(env)
ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()

# your code here

ctx.pop()
```

This is from the docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context) and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/shell/#creating-a-request-context).

Answer (score 15):

I know this question has been answered but you can also use the `with` statement:

```
from my_package import create_app

app = create_app(my_envrionment)

with app.app_context():
    # your code here
```

I think this looks a little cleaner :)

Answer (score 6):

Another elegant way to solve this is using the @with_appcontext decorator.

```
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

@click.command(name='db-init-data')
@with_appcontext
def db_init_data():
    """Init db with some data"""
    admin = User(fname='John', lname='Smith', email='jsmith@google.com')
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.commit()
```