# models module for flask application

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask application `foo`, up until this point this is how files are organized

```
foo
|-- app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|
|-- foo.py
```

in `__init__.py` I define a function to create the app, which it is then called from `foo.py`. This is how `__init__.py` looks like:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
```

The module `models.py` imports `db` and access an **existing database**. So far I've been using `db.engine.execute(<...>)` to make queries, but it seems kind of inefficient. For example, I have a table called `var` which I constantly access in my app, so I define a class in `models.py`

```
class Var(object):       
   def query ...
```

but I'd like to use `alchemy` instead:

```
class Var(db.Model):
    ...
```

I tried to follow the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database) to build my application, but these are the problems I've found so far

1. If I insert `base.metadata.reflect(db.engine)` inside the `create_app` function I get an error saying I need to create a context, which doesn't make a lot of sense, since this is the the place where I'm creating it. Of course, if I do `with app.app_context(): base.metadata.reflect(db.engine)` I can get around, but then the problem is still there when I create the class `Var`:

   class Var(db.Model): 
       **table** = db.Model.metadata.tables['var']

The dictionary is empty, so I get a `KeyError`.

2. When I try to create a [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060553/creating-a-database-outside-the-application-context) inside `models` to create my class `Var` it also fails, because it cannot import it.

I've tried all the suggestions I've found, but none of them seems to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to set `table` inside the model, `db.Model` already sets the table for you.

Comment: @LuisOrduz I see, so how do I link the the class `Var` to the table `var`?

Comment: The class `Var` is the table. To create it you just need to import the class to where you're running the `create_all` method.

Comment: This is what I get `ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Var|var could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'var'`, which I assume implies I need to define the structure of the table (columns, primary keys, ...), is that the solution?

Comment: You aren't adding a primary key to your table. `class Var(db.Model): ... id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) ...`

Comment: @LuisOrduz Thanks, how about the other columns? Do I need to declare them as well? Say the table `var` has columns `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `id`, do I need write `c1 = db.Column(db.Integer), ...`. This would imply to pretty copy the structure of the db into my code, which will turn out into a problem if the db is migrated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178939/discussion-between-luis-orduz-and-caverac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` that, like most flask extensions, is tied with flask and, for running certain tasks, it needs a flask context but, to reflect an already existing database, you need an engine independent of any request.

You could probably still use `db` by using `with app.app_context()` wherever you need, but it's probably better to not use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and instead use `SQLAlchemy` directly and use `create_engine`, like in the question you linked.