# Connecting a flask app to existing database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a flask application with a database, but the database already exists. I don't want to have to define all of my tables again in Python (e.g. in `models.py`) code just to interact with the database, since this would be doing the same thing twice (sort of). But I can't seem to find a clear example of how to do this. I can see several questions asking the same thing but the response is not clear.

In my `__init__.py` file, I have

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

...

db = SQLAlchemy()
Base = automap_base()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
    Base.prepare(autoload_with=db.engine, schema="my_schema")
```

And then in my `models.py` file, I have

```
from . import db, Base

MyTable = Base.classes.my_table
```

I simply want to import `MyTable` into the `views.py` and run queries from it, as you would with standard Flask-SQLAlchemy. But on trying to start the app, I receive:

```
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I do not want to solve this error - I want to access my database correctly, because I am sure that I am doing this wrong. As I have never used SQLAlchemy properly, only basic Flask-SQLAlchemy, I am pretty lost. Is there an obvious/simple/clear/recommended way to just connect and use an existing database in my flask app?

Comment: Well it looks promising, but it actually leaves me with the same error `RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.`. It seems that the line `db.Model.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine,schema='DATABASE_NAME')` causes this now. I placed this directly under my `db.init_app(app)`.

Comment: I don't think that error relates to reflection directly - I think you need to run .reflect inside a context as mentioned [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy) if you follow the `init_app` approach.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24060553/5320906).

Comment: This is what I mean by not wanting to just fix the error because this approach seems wrong. Why should I have to use with app.app_context() just to get this to work right underneath initialising the app? There surely has to be a recommended way to do this.

Comment: I've linked to the official docs and a Q&A with an accepted answer by Flask-SQLA's maintainer - what more do you want.  Reflecting the database and the error message about application context are _separate issues_.

Comment: I understand that they are separate and tried to acknowledge this in my initial question. I think the problem is that it probably works with a non-factory structure but when there is this structure it throws this error. Resolving the specific error (which happens for a lot of different reasons) in this case does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True, future=True)
session = Session(engine)
```